# Undefined variable: nombre (View: C:\wamp64\www\curso-laravel\prueba-laravel\resources\views\Contacto.blade.php)

Tags: undefined

Buenas espero puedan ayudarme estoy creando una ruta tipo get a la cual le estoy pasando dos variables mediante una funcion pero al momento de actualizar la pagina me dice el siguiente error:

Undefined variable: nombre (View: C:\wamp64\www\curso-laravel\prueba-laravel\resources\views\Contacto.blade.php)

este es el codigo de la ruta:

```
Route::get('contacto/{nombre?}/{edad?}', function($nombre = "Andres Guerrero", $edad = "26")
{
    return view('contacto', array(
        "nombre" => $nombre,
        "edad" => $edad));
})->where (['nombre'=>'[A-Za-z]+','edad' =>'[0-9]+');
```

Este es el codigo de la vista donde quiero mostrar esa informacion:

```
<h1>Nombre de Contacto   {{$nombre}} {{$edad}}</h1>
```

Comment: Pues yo reproduje tu ejercicio y es totalmente funcional, salvo que aquí: `(['nombre'=>'[A-Za-z]+','edad' =>'[0-9]+');` al final te falta un corchete para cerrar `(['nombre'=>'[A-Za-z]+','edad' =>'[0-9]+']);`

Comment: La verdad es que no entiendo porque a mi me generar un error de sintaxys